# getMilliseconds() out of Java Date

Tags: java, date, milliseconds

I need a function like
long getMillis(Date aDate);

that returns the milliseconds of the Date second.
I cannot use Yoda, SimpleDateFormat or other libraries because it's gwt code.

My current solution is doing `date.getTime() % 1000`

Is there a better way?

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution? Looks good to me.

Comment: I'd do as you did. Seems to be a pretty natural way of working it out. I'm not 100% sure, but the clock precision of the computer may vary (so you may not have to-the-ms granularity in all situations.

Comment: @Harry That's javascript

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick feedback. Java Dates are really crap IMHO.

Comment: @Romain, this will work for dates from 1/1/1970.  The % 1000 only does suprising things for negative numbers e.g. dates before 1970.

Comment: @Peter, indeed. I've also seen systems which clock only gives 5ms granularity, so if you want to rely on it for sub-5ms detail, you're screwed.

Comment: On Windows systems before Vista the granularity was 1/60th of a second (~16 ms).  This means the Date is not as accurate as it could be, there is nothing wrong with the line the OP posted however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed by Peter Lawrey, in general you need something like

```
int n = (int) (date.getTime() % 1000);
return n<0 ? n+1000 : n;
```

since `%` works in a "strange" way in Java. I call it strange, as I *always* need the result to fall into a given range (here: 0..999), rather than sometimes getting negative results. Unfortunately, it works this way in most CPUs and most languages, so we have to live with it.

Comment: Removed statement about: "%" being strange.  Rollback if you really want to say that.

Comment: Agreed: it's standard. However, the standard is broken, as for negative numbers it rarely does what you need. Take this question as an example for where you need the result to always fall in range 0..999. Is there an example where you need the negative result? I doubt it.

Comment: @m I think the confusion is that you said "%" can be strange when I think you meant date.getTime() can be strange.

Comment: Just wanted to mention when I ran this code as-is, it caused 'n' to get a negative result erroneously, and when I changed from 'int' to use 'long' things worked as expected and there was no more integer overflow.

Comment: @kvr Thanks! Funny that nobody noticed it for so long! `+++` There were missing parentheses in my code causing a conversion to `int` *before* the division. But the division must use `long` operands. Thereafter, we have a number in range -999..+999, which fits.

Answer (score 3):

Tried above and got unexpected behavior until I used the mod with 1000 as a long.

```
int n = (int) (date.getTime() % 1000l);
return n<0 ? n+1000 : n;
```

Comment: do you have an example of it failing?

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
aDate.toInstant()
     .toEpochMilli()
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses java.time classes. These supplant the troublesome old legacy classes such as `java.util.Date`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

Extract your count of milliseconds since epoch of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

```
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

## Converting

If you are passed a `java.util.Date` object, convert to java.time. Call new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```